# Links in an e-mail working in Outlook, but not in Gmail - any tips?

Tags: email, hyperlink, gmail

I compose an e-mail with PHP that includes an A-tag to automatically login to my website and jump to a certain page.

In Outlook everything works fine, but Gmail and Ipad Mail show the link as normal text only, so you can not click on it.  Somehow the link is not trusted, I guess, because another short link to my webpage in the e-mail DOES work.

Here's an example of the link, it doesn't work because of security reasons, but you get the idea :

**`<a id="Example" href="abc.domain.nl/loginlink.php?user=J535ZAFH&password=829%23221&screenid=SCREEN_USER&operation=VIEW&params=actiesoortid=REAGEREN&primaryfieldname=_jgubzp%7Fl%60k%7CmlPQ&primaryfieldvalue=%3E%3D%230%3C%28&optionprofile=150&userprofile=4">`**

(the username, password , primaryfieldname and primaryfieldvalue are encrypted for more security)

Obviously the URL is very long and doesn's start with 'www', maybe that's the reason, but I don't really see an easy way to shorten the URL and change the subdomain.
Maybe it's because the 'params' paramater has a double = ?

Are there maybe any things I can do to get this working in other mail-programs than Outlook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `target='_blank'`  and now the link works in Gmail too!

Answer (score 1):

At first sight I notice there is no "http://" in the href attribute this means the link is relative, so it shouldn't work either in Outlook.
Try prepending http:// (or whatever protocol it is).

Comment: That could be it!  (The other link that does work has http:// in front of it). I'll try it out. Without http:// DOES work in Outlook though.

Comment: GMail is quite restrictive when interpreting html formatted messages. Your field values contain a lot of encoded unsafe characters(%3E, %3D...) I suggest you change the encryption method.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your headers are right:

$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7BIT";

not:

$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable";

Comment: This took me two days to find! When I looked in Docs ... there it was. Thanks